# Python coding style from Java background

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-2.x

I am pretty new to Python and just wanted to make sure I am going in the right direction with my coding style.

After reading [this](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), I'm not so sure.

The following is a convenience class that has operations used a lot in my main code.

```
import requests

try: import simplejson as json
except ImportError: import json

"""
Basic operations involving users
"""

#The URL of the API
api_root = "http://api.stuff.com/v1/core";

class UserOperations(object):
    def __init__(self, headers):
        self.headers = headers

    def move_user(self,source_account,destination_account, user_id):

        user_id = str(user_id)

        #Get user
        user = self.get_user(source_account, user_id)

        if user is not None:

            #Remove user from source account
            self.remove_user(source_account, user_id)

            #Add user to destination account
            self.add_user(destination_account, user)

    def get_user(self, account_id, user_id):

        #Get user
        user = requests.get(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id, headers=self.headers)

        #Throw exception if non-200 response
        user.raise_for_status()

        print "\nGet User " + user_id + ": " + user.text

        #Check user exists
        if user.json()['Data'] is None:
            return None

        #Return user
        return user.json()['Data']

    def remove_user(self,account_id, user_id):

        #Delete a user
        result = requests.delete(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id, headers=self.headers)                
        #Throw exception if non-200 response
        result.raise_for_status()
        #Result of delete operation
        print "\nDelete Result " + result.text

    def add_user(self,account_id, user):

        #Add user to new account
        result = requests.post(api_root + '/accounts/' + account_id + '/users', data=json.dumps(user), headers=self.headers)
        #Throw exception if non-200 response
        result.raise_for_status()
        #Result of add operation
        print "\nAdd User: " + result.text
```

Does this seem on the right track or are there any Python mantra's I'm missing out on.

**Edit**

Function to replace below code duplication

```
variable = requests.get(api_root + "/accounts/"....)
variable.raise_for_status()
```

Function:

```
def request(self, request, account_id, user):

    if request is 'get':
        #Get user
        result = requests.get(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id, headers=self.headers)
    elif request is 'post':
        #Add user to new account
        result = requests.post(api_root + '/accounts/' + account_id + '/users', data=json.dumps(user), headers=self.headers)
    elif request is 'delete':
        #Delete user from account
        result = requests.delete(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id, headers=self.headers)

    #Throw exception if non-200 response
    result.raise_for_status()
    return result
```

**Edit**
Function attempt 2:

```
def request(self, request, account_id, user):

    function_dict = {}
    function_dict['get'] = requests.get(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user, headers=self.headers)
    function_dict['post'] = requests.post(api_root + '/accounts/' + account_id + '/users', data=json.dumps(user), headers=self.headers)
    function_dict['delete'] = requests.delete(api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user, headers=self.headers)

    result = function_dict.get(request)

    #Throw exception if non-200 response
    result.raise_for_status()
    return result
```

Comment: Ugh, if..elif..elif  That's a bad smell.  Use a dictionary to map the request verb to the appropriate function.  Raise an exception if there is no key in the dictionary to match the request method.

Comment: Updated question, is this any cleaner?

Comment: Some.  But now look at those three lines where you define the functions to go in the dictionary; see how much duplication there is.  You shouldn't be retyping almost the same thing again and again.  The OO solution (you being an alleged Java geek) would be to create a request object that knows how to construct a basic request and uri, and specialisations thereof which can fill in the blanks for a particular verb.  Those objects could go into a dictionary and their methods called as necessary.  I'm sure there are more idiomatic alternatives that also avoid the duplication.

Comment: Right I tried a couple of things but keep ending up with my second example, any chance you could shed some light on this mysterious enigma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Unlike in Java, not everything in Python needs to be a class. In Python we tend to reserve classes for representing *things* with individual state and common behaviour. If you just want to group some functions together, you can put them in a *module*.
2. You have no documentation. What do these functions do and how am I supposed to call them? In Python you should give every public class, function and method a *docstring*.
3. Why do you try importing [`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/)? This is just the externally maintained version of the built-in [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. You don't seem to use any `simplejson`-specific feature, so what's the point?
4. Your code is not portable to Python 3, but this would be easy to fix by putting parentheses around the arguments to `print`.
5. This code:

   ```
   #Check user exists
   if user.json()['Data'] is None:
       return None

   #Return user
   return user.json()['Data']
   ```

   can be simplified to:

   ```
   return user.json()['Data']
   ```
6. You have code like this:

   ```
   VARIABLE = requests.METHOD(api_root + '/accounts/' + account_id + STUFF, headers=self.headers)
   VARIABLE.raise_for_status()
   ```

   in three places. You should make this a function.
7. It's not clear what the point of this line is:

   ```
   user_id = str(user_id)
   ```

   All you ever do with `user_id` is add it to strings, where it will be converted to a string in any case.
8. I prefer to use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to build up strings, rather than `+`: the former tends to result in clearer code. For example:

   ```
   api_root + "/accounts/" + account_id + "/users/" + user_id
   ```

   would become:

   ```
   '{}/accounts/{}/users/{}'.format(api_root, account_id, user_id)
   ```

#### Comment on updated question

You have failed to avoid the duplicated code: you have just moved it around.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Just a couple of questions, 1) To turn this piece of code into a module, would I just remove the class definition? 2)Each of those functions require a variable called `headers`, would it be better to pass them in when calling the function?

3)How does the function look for removing the duplicate code? (Updated question)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't spot how to remove the code duplication, how can I make a generic function and differentiate between different types of requests?

Comment: @Tomcelic You really need to go back and re-read that page you linked to.  I just read it and I can see one issue (if..elif) to which the author gives the same solution I did - so since you read that page before coming here, why didn't you take his advice.  There is more advice on his page which would also help.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with Gareth, here are my additions:

1. Don't use compound statements; better formatting (as recommended by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19)):

   ```
   try:
       import simplejson as json
   except ImportError:
       import json
   ```
2. I don't add strings either, when I can avoid it; my preferred solution would be (very suitable for i18n, by the way):

   ```
   '%(api_root)s/accounts/%(account_id)s/users/%(user_id)s' % locals()
   ```